# OnChange unknow parameter in delphi

Tags: delphi

I have procedure:

```
procedure TFMain.CariNamaChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
ADOQdata.Close;
ADOQdata.SQL.Clear;
ADOQdata.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM data WHERE nama like :nam');
ADOQdata.Parameters.ParamByName('nam').Value := CariNama.Text;
ADOQdata.open;
end;
```

If I compile, this is the found error:

> ADOData parameter nam not found

Help me.

Comment: It looks to me that the field name is 'name' and the contents like a variable called 'nam'. It other words the ParameterByName parameter should be 'name'.

Comment: @Dsm: Don't know SQL, but I guess the parameter might be `'nama'`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis - I must get some new glasses! Yes you are right.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `ADOQdata.Prepare` in there somewhere? Or at least something that (re)parses the SQL to populate the Parameters collection?

Comment: @StijnSanders should be `ADOQdata.Prepared := True;` if I read the Docs correctly. The parameter name seems to be correct @Rudy.

Comment: Why does the error refer to ADOData and not ADOQData?